# How to send a email automatically from a .net application without using smtp server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
In my lab smtp server is blocked.I had gone through the EAsendmail package but i couldn't succeed in sending email from the application directly without using going through smtp server.
```

here is the code

```
SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();
//Set sender email address, please change it to yours
oMail.From = "yaswanthmdh@gmail.com";

//Set recipient email address, please change it to yours
oMail.To = "manojsr6@gmail.com";

//Set email subject
oMail.Subject = "direct email sent from c# project";

//Set email body
oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project directly";

//Set SMTP server address to "".
SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");//173.194.40.246,"74.125.237.181");

//Set 465 port
oServer.Port = 465;

//detect SSL/TLS automatically
oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

//Gmail user authentication
//For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be the same
oServer.User = "yaswanthmdh@gmail.com";
oServer.Password = "";

try
{
Console.WriteLine("start to send email directly ...");
oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
}
catch (Exception ep)
{
Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
}
```

after running this code i am getting timeout error.
is there any other way to send an email other than through smtp?
is there any way to send an email from application through http?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's how email works. Just like you need a web server to serve web pages, you need an SMTP server to send email. You'll have to talk to your IT Infrastructure department, and get them to either set something up for you or allow requests to whatever SMTP server you're trying to use.

If you just need to test sending email, you can use something like [Papercut](https://papercut.codeplex.com/), for the time being, and then depending on where and how you deploy your application in production, it may no longer be a problem.

Comment: sir i have doubt even though in our lab smtp server is closed then how i am able to see my gmail.

Comment: Well, first *receiving* mail works over a different port and different protocol (IMAP or POP). Second, with Gmail, it's very likely you're viewing it on the web, in which case, all the protocol stuff happens behind the scenes on Google's servers. All you're doing is sending an receiving bits over the standard HTTP(S) protocol on port 80, which will be allowed pretty much universally.